# The module $\Omega^1_{\mathcal{O}_E|\mathbf{Z}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I have been learning about Kähler differentials recently. If $E$ is an algebraic number field, then it is natural to consider the $\mathcal{O}_E$-module of Kähler differentials $\Omega^1_{\mathcal{O}_E|\mathbf{Z}}$. What arithmetic information about $E$, in particular ramification information, does this module contain? What are its general properties? I have read elsewhere that it is finite (as a set)?

Comment: If $a$ is in $E$, there is an integer polynomial $f$ such that $f(a)=0$, and then $f'(a)da=0$. This means that every $da$ is torsion in $\Omega$. It is easy to see that if a set $X$ generates $E$ as a ring over $Z$, then $\{dx:x\in X\}$ generates $\Omega$ as a module. This shows finiteness.

Comment: It's annihilator is exactly the different ideal, which gives you almost all ramification information (everything except for wild ramification).